# How do i fix this value code

Tags: javascript

So i want to get this working! Lets say value is within 93-120% of value2, i want the text to change to working or not working!

The issue is i do not know how i am able to do if value is greater than or equal to percentage of value2! I am sure this is an easy fix/line of code.

Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Display the result here.</p>

<script>
var value = 30;
var value2 = 27;

if (value >= 93% "of lets say value2" && value <= 120% "of same value2") {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Working";
} else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Not Working";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the (how to ask)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Can you clarify what's going wrong, and what you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (value >= 0.93*value2 && value <= 1.2*value2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this simple math:

> `if (value >= 93% "of lets say value2" && value <= 120% "of same value2")`

```
if ( (value/value2) > 0.93 && (value/value2) < 1.2 )
```

---

***Note:***

No need to check for zero of if the values are set (not undefined).
Since if there is any error of this kind it will be `NaN` or `Infinity`

[image]

Comment: Attention… in case value2 happens to be zero 

Comment: No need to , in JavaScript division by zero yields to infinity (as mush as its surprising)